# Почему QMetaObject::invokeMethod не изменяет переменную в QGenericReturnArgument если Q_INVOKABLE-функция возвращает ссылку?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, рефлексия

**Работающий код, функция testValue() возвращает копию значения:**

```
class Node : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
//some code
Q_INVOKABLE int testValue() {return _test;}
//some code
private:
int _test = 5;
//some code
};
```

Вызываем фнкцию testValue через invokeMethod:

```
int testValue;
world->metaObject()->invokeMethod(world, "testValue", Q_RETURN_ARG(int, testValue));
qDebug() << "TEST VALUE:" << testValue; //5
```

Все хорошо, видим на экране **5**

---

**Тот же код, но функция testValue возвращает ссылку:**

```
class Node : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
//some code
Q_INVOKABLE int &testValue() {return _test;}
//some code
private:
int _test = 5;
//some code
};
```

вызываем invokeMethod:

```
int testValue;
world->metaObject()->invokeMethod(world, "testValue", Q_RETURN_ARG(int, testValue));
qDebug() << "TEST VALUE:" << testValue; //?
```

значение testValue не меняется и вывод зависит от платформы

---

**Так не работает тоже:**

```
int testValue;
world->metaObject()->invokeMethod(world, "testValue", Q_RETURN_ARG(int&, testValue));
qDebug() << "TEST VALUE:" << testValue; //?
```

---

**Определим тип intamp, но тоже не работает:**

```
typedef int& intamp;
int testValue;
world->metaObject()->invokeMethod(world, "testValue", Q_RETURN_ARG(intamp, testValue));
qDebug() << "TEST VALUE:" << testValue;
```

---

**PS** Может понадобиться, если функция возвращает ссылку на массивный объект, здесь привел более простой и академический пример, чтобы понять, почему нельзя использовать ссылку в `Q_RETURN_ARG`, не нашел прямого упоминания об этом в документации QT